# How to set relative path to script from ascx

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have created custom DNN module.
And I want to use [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) plugin in it.
So in the module project in VS I have created **Scripts** folder and put **JS** files in there.
On the view of ascx file I have added:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/imagesloaded.js"></script>
```

But when I load the page eith module in console I get:

```
GET http://dnn7site/resources/shared/scripts/jquery/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) Masonry:457
GET http://dnn7site/jquery.min.map 404 (Not Found) Masonry:464
GET http://dnn7site/Demos/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js 404 (Not Found) Masonry:751
GET http://dnn7site/Demos/Scripts/imagesloaded.js 404 (Not Found) Masonry:752
GET http://dnn7site/Demos/Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js 404 (Not Found)
```

What is the way to add and set a relative path to the scripts in DNN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including the full path to the resource files, as per the instructions on the [Masonry getting started documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started):

*Include the Masonry script in your site.*

```
<script src="/path/to/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

For example:

```
<script src="/desktopmodules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="/desktopmodules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js"></script>
<script src="/desktopmodules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/imagesloaded.js"></script>
```

Comment: still 404 but Demos lost from path.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the `~/` - try that.  Obviously this will only work if the `Scripts` folders resides straight off the root, which I'm assuming it is.

Comment: Still 404 and path is now:
`GET http://dnn7site/Demos/~/Scripts/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js 404 (Not Found) Masonry:750
GET http://dnn7site/Demos/~/Scripts/imagesloaded.js 404 (Not Found) Masonry:752
GET http://dnn7site/Demos/~/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js 404 (Not Found) `

Comment: What should the path be? Can you manually browse to the script files using your browser address bar?

Comment: In the browser I can open file like this:
`http://dnn7site/desktopmodules/com.demo.masonry/Scripts/masonry.pkgd.js`

Comment: Have you tried including the full path then?  I've updated my answer as per Masonry [documentation](http://masonry.desandro.com/#getting-started).

Comment: Yes. Than helps me to solve issue but now missing jquery but this is speceific to dnn so I will start new question. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should be using the client dependency framework to include scripts in DotNetNuke (feature was added in DNN 6.1+). It will control priority and allow the framework to combine scripts together for a more efficient payload.

The wiki entry for the information is here:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/Page/Client-Resource-Management-API

In essence, it's as easy as this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dnn" Namespace="DotNetNuke.Web.Client.ClientResourceManagement" Assembly="DotNetNuke.Web.Client" %>

<dnn:DnnJsInclude runat="server" FilePath="~/Resources/Shared/Scripts/jquery/jquery.hoverIntent.min.js" />
```

If you want to do it through code, try this:

```
RegisterStyleSheet(Page page, string filePath) //default provider and default priority
```

Answer (score 2):

For scripts or css in my custom module, I usually put the call to ClientResourceManager in my control's PreRender event.  I use the ControlPath to get the relative path of my module control to reference the scripts.  Example:

```
protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
{
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterStyleSheet(this.Page, this.ControlPath + "css/view.css");
    ClientResourceManager.RegisterScript(this.Page, this.ControlPath + "js/view.js");
}
```